# Java bundle Jar with text files and folders

Tags: java, file, jar, bundle, exe

Facing a slight issue here. I have a project that reads from multiple textfiles and moves files between folders. Is there any way to bundle these files together with the jar? Since i'll have to wrap the jar in an Executable.

Thanks

Comment: You can simply put the files inside the jar, at the root or in any subdirectory. They then can be read by calling `Class.getResourceAsStream(...)`.

Comment: It should be bundled by default if the files are in the src/main/resources directory when using something like maven.

Comment: @Rogério 's comment should be an answer. you place your files inside your jar and read them by getting an input stream to them.

Comment: @Rogerio Thanks that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You can package anything with a jar. A jar is basically just a zip file. From the [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

> The basic format of the command for creating a JAR file is:
>
> jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
>
> The options and arguments used in this command are:
>
> The c option indicates that you want to create a JAR file.
>
> The f option indicates that you want the output to go to a file rather than to stdout.
>
> jar-file is the name that you want the resulting JAR file to have. You
>   can use any filename for a JAR file. By convention, JAR filenames are
>   given a .jar extension, though this is not required.
>
> The input-file(s) argument is a space-separated list of one or more
>   files that you want to include in your JAR file. The input-file(s)
>   argument can contain the wildcard * symbol. If any of the
>   "input-files" are directories, the contents of those directories are
>   added to the JAR archive recursively.